# OO JavaScript - Avoiding self = this

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a way to get around declaring var self = this when using JavaScript in an OO fashion? I see it quite often and was curious if its just something you have to do, or if there really is a way (perhaps a class library?) that lets you get around it? I do realize why it is necessary (this has function scope). But you never know what clever ways may be out there..

For example, I usually code my "classes" like this in JS:

```
function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.prototype = {

    firstFunction: function() {

        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function() {
                self.someFunctionCall();

            }
        });
    },

    secondFunction: function() {

        var self = this;

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            self.someOtherFunction();
        }, 1000);
    }

};
```

Comment: I just want to point out that you should really set the `constructor` property of the `prototype` to point back to `MyClass` since you set it to another object. Just append the following line to your code: `MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first function you can do this...

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    success: function() {
        this.someFunctionCall();

    }
});
```

---

In the second one, you can do this, though you'll need to shim [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in older browsers...

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    this.someOtherFunction();
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

---

With jQuery, you could also do this...

```
window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    this.someOtherFunction();
}, this), 1000);
```

Comment: using `this` inside of an anonymous function will not give you a reference to `MyClass`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: In all my solutions, `this` will be a reference to `MyClass`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how it works to me? I am missing something

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: The `$.ajax` one sets the `this` value of the callback by setting the `context:` property. The second one uses `Function.prototype.bind` to permanently bind the `this` value to the function, and the third one uses `$.proxy`, which is sort of like a light version of `Function.prototype.bind`.

Comment: Thank you, that was really informative; sorry for doubting :)

Comment: Those are some cool solutions. Never knew that jQuery provided those conventions.

Comment: @BrianD.: The `.bind()` one isn't jQuery. That's the one to use when jQuery isn't around, or maybe even when it is.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to do this if you want to refer to `this` in a different context (such as a callback) since otherwise it will be reassigned to another object such as `window`.

By the way, `self` is a python convention - in JavaScript people generally use the convention `that = this`. But it is just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: I've seen self, that, and obj used in js.

Comment: YMMV.  I think I've seen `self` a dozen times in Javascript for every `that`.

Comment: I've seen a lot of `that`, but I find it semantically wrong. `this` and `that`, as words, are basically opposites. But we want them to refer to the same object.

Comment: @Imp: Think of it this way: "this" and "that" are often used together in English in opposition where "this" refers to the closer item; "that" refers to the more remote one. Or, alternately, "this" is mine, whereas "that" is someone else's/not mine. When you set `that=this`, you're preparing to pass the current execution context's owner object to another execution context--one in which `this` points to a different object, and so the object referenced by `that` _is_ indeed the other, more remote item.

Comment: I've also seen more `self`s than `that`s, and I think it's clearer, but clearer still is something altogether more descriptive, such as, in the original example, `var myClass = this;`.

Answer (score 1):

ES5 added the standard method called `bind` which allows you to bind the `this` of a function as well as the first n number of parameters. In the example above, you can avoid using `self` by calling `bind`.

```
$.ajax({ 
    ... 
    success: function() { 
        this.someFunctionCall(); 
    }.bind(this); 
});
```

For non-ES5 browsers you can use a shim for it such as the one found here: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

As an asside, I would avoid using `self` in your coding pattern because `self` is defined as a global variable that is equal to `window` which is the global scope. In other words, if you accidentally forget to define `self` you will silently get the global scope as the value instead of an exception. If you use `that` instead, you will get an exception (unless someone above you defined it).

Answer (score 0):

Some javascript frameworks have their own event handling mechanisms that allow you to set context for the handler function. This way, instead of using `self = this`, you can simply specify `this` as the context.

Other possibility that comes to my mind is to pass the context in somewhere in global scope. Like

```
function MyClass() {
    MyClass.instances.push(this);
}

MyClass.instances = new Array();
MyClass.getInstanceBySomeRelevantParameter = function(param) {
     for (var i = 0; i < MyClass.instances.length; i++)
         if (condition(param))
             return MyClass.instances[i];
}

...

success: function(event) {
    MyClass.getInstanceBySomeRelevantParameter(event).someFunctionCall();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may always bind your methods to `this` and then use it as follows:

```
function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.prototype = {

    firstFunction: function() {

        var funct = someFunctionCall.bind(this);

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function() {
                funct();

            }
        });
    },

    secondFunction: function() {

        var funct = someOtherFunction.bind(this);

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            funct();
        }, 1000);
    }

};
```

For properties just assign them to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

I fooled around on JSFiddle, and came up with the below. It does assume that you are using a top level namespace. This makes it so you only need to declare self once (at the bottom). I wrapped the class in an anonymous function so self wouldn't have a global scope. The fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/bdicasa/yu4vs/

```
var App = {};
(function() {
    App.MyClass = function() { }

    App.MyClass.prototype = {

        firstFunction: function() {

            console.log('in first function');
            console.log(self === this); // true
        },

        secondFunction: function() {


            window.setTimeout(function() {
                self.firstFunction();
                console.log(self === this); // false
            }, 100);
        }

    };
    var self = App.MyClass.prototype;
})();

var myClass = new App.MyClass();
myClass.secondFunction();
```

Comment: This doesn't set the `self` to the element invoking the function. In other words, `self` inside your methods will be `App.MyClass.prototype`, not the `myClass` instance. If you define the `var that = this;` in the methods, then do `console.log(that === self);` in the `setTimeout` callback, you'll see that it returns `false`.

Comment: Hmm. Good catch, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It's just one of those unfortunate aspects of JavaScript. There's no implicit transfer of calling context to a nested function. So all you can do is use one of the workarounds.